# website login via vba failure: timeout expired error message

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, timeout

I am a complete beginner to web programming, and I want to download a file from my banking site via vba excel. the code fills in the form all right and clicks the login buttin, but the website refuses to sign in because "timeout expired".
How can I solve this problem?

Is a cookie missing, and how can it be provided?

```
Sub Login()      'provokes timeout error from the server
  Dim IEApp As Object
  Dim ding As Object
  Dim IEDoc As Object  
  Set IEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IEApp.Visible = True
  IEApp.navigate "https://www.mybank/banking"
  Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set IEDoc = IEApp.document
  On Error Resume Next 

  With IEApp.document
     Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

     For Each ding In IEDoc.all             'username eintragen
         If ding.Name = "j_username" Then
            If Err = 0 Then
               ding.Value = "myUsername"
               On Error GoTo 0
               Err.Clear
               Exit For
            Else
               Err.Clear
            End If
         End If
     Next

     Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

     On Error Resume Next
     For Each ding In IEDoc.all              'passwort eintragen
           If ding.Name = "j_password" Then
            If Err = 0 Then
               ding.Value = "myPassword"
               On Error GoTo 0
               Err.Clear
               Exit For
            Else
               Err.Clear
            End If
         End If
     Next  

     Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop  

     On Error Resume Next                     'button 'login'
     For Each ding In IEDoc.all               
           If ding.Title = "login" And ding.Type = "button" Then
            If Err = 0 Then
               ding.Click
               On Error GoTo 0
               Err.Clear
               Exit For
            Else
               Err.Clear
            End If
         End If
     Next  

  End With 

  Set ding = Nothing
  Set IEDoc = Nothing
  Set IEApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that

```
Sub Login()      'provokes timeout error from the server
  Dim IEApp As Object
  Dim ding As Object
  Dim IEDoc As Object
  Set IEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IEApp.Visible = True
  IEApp.navigate "https://www.mybank/banking"
  Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set IEDoc = IEApp.document
  On Error Resume Next

  With IEApp.document
     Do While IEApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    With IEApp
        .document.getelementsbyname("j_username")(0).Value = "myUsername"
        .document.getelementsbyname("j_password")(0).Value = "myPassword"
    End With
```

Comment: Hi Ronan, yes, it woks as far as it goes. But my code does the same thing. Problem comes, when I submit username and password. Errormessage either "cookies deactivated" or "session timeout", while cookies are NOT deactivated.

Comment: Maybe it is a IE Security problem ? Open IE Settings and disable safe mode